# How do i clear the parameters in a link in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

Hi i'm working on a calender when you click a day it shows you all tasks for that day.
this is the code in the view.

```
$calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
    $calendar.= '<a href="evenement/showTaken/day/'. $list_day .'/maand/'.$month.'/jaar/'.$year.'">';
    $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';


        /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
                   $_evenement = new evenement();
                    $taak = $_evenement -> dateChecker($list_day,$month,$year);
        $calendar.= $taak;


    $calendar.= '</a></td>';
```

this is the code in the controller

```
public function showTaken(){
   $this->load->model('model_taak');
    $get = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
    $dag = $get['day'];
    $maand = $get['maand'];
    $jaar = $get['jaar'];
    $datum = date('M Y', mktime(0,0,0,$maand + 1,0,$jaar));

    $this->load->template('view_evenement', 'evenement', array(
        'maand' => $maand,
        'jaar' => $jaar,
        'datum' => $datum,
        'infovandaag' => $dag.'/'.$maand.'/'.$jaar,
        'taakvandaag' => $this->model_taak->takenByDate($dag.'/'.$maand.'/'.$jaar)
```

the problem i have is that when i click multiple days after eachother the link ends up something like this and will keep showing the first day clicked.

/code/index.php/evenement/evenement/showTaken/day/2/maand/2/jaar/evenement/showTaken/day/3/maand/03/jaar/evenement/showTaken/day/4/maand/03/jaar/evenement/showTaken/day/4/maand/03/jaar/2014

any idea how i could solve this? 
this is the first time i post here so i hope i gave you enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `href="evenement/..."` is a relative URL and is getting appended to the current URL. You have two options:

1. Place an absolute URL in your code, e.g. `href="http://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/code/index.php/evenement/..."` or `href="/path/to/code/index.php/evenement/..."`
2. Provide a base href in the `<head>` of the page, e.g. `<base href="http://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/code/index.php/">`.
3. Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to generate an absolute URL.

Here is an example for #3:

```
<?php
list ($url) = explode('index.php/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$calendar.= '<a href="'.$url.'/evenement/showTaken/day/'. $list_day .'/maand/'.$month.'/jaar/'.$year.'">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a leading slash '/' in front of "event" on your second line :

```
$calendar.= '<a href="/evenement/showTaken/day/'. $list_day .'/maand/'.$month.'/jaar/'.$year.'">';
```

Or even better, use CodeIgniter url generation :

```
$calendar.= '<a href="<=site_url('/evenement/showTaken/day/'.$list_day.'/maand/'.$month.'/jaar/'.$year);?>">';
```